# Managing login in php

Tags: php, loginstatus

Obviously I have my own opinion and way of doing this, but I would be curious to see if there were any better ways.

How do you manage logins, i.e. check if user is logged in with valid login before serving members only content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make use of [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)s
- Start every single page with [session_start();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
- Check for a custom `$_SESSION` variable for member content (`$_SESSION['username']`)
- If your variable isn't presented, display a login form
- Upon successful login set `$_SESSION['username']` to currently logged in user's nickname

<sub>Note: This is a brief description of managing logins, there are a lot of things isn't described here. You should avoid different security holes like [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [session-hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), etc)</sub>

Comment: But why Sessions over Cookies?

Comment: $_SESSIONS can be easily managed on the server-side so you don't rely on users' browser settings. (If cookies doesn't allowed on the client side.) Of course there's a lot of pros/cons on both side thus the best option is combine both imho.

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time, I made a Session class, which was instantiated in a common include file. Rather than using `session_*` and `$_SESSION`, it used a cookie with a client-side SID (I think it was a SHA-256 hash with salt and a few iterations). On the server, the client-side SID went into another hashing function a few times to get the server-side SID, which was the primary key in a remote MySQL database.

Why? Because the site was on shared hosting, but the sessions needed to be secure as the database held details of people under 18. PHP by default uses `/tmp` as the place to store session data as serialised files, meaning that anyone with access to `/tmp` (i.e. any other customer on the same host) could access the serialised form of session data and possibly use it to appear authenticated.

It was a good way for me to learn about session handling, HTTP headers etc. and it felt much nicer to work with than the standard PHP way.

Answer (score 1):

I check the authentication cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I would not manage it myself anymore. There are just too much things that can go **WRONG**. Instead I would use **OpenID** just like stackoverflow.com does.

Comment: even if it is closed you can use openid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but i'm used to create a user class and create the object when i create a **new** session.
I store this object into the session and i'm used to link the session var to an enviroment var, just to avoid to deal with the $_SESSION array.
In this way you can keep the login method and the login status inside the object itself, together with all the information related to the user (name, surname, access level, etc)

something like that:

```
include('user.class.php');
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
   $_SESSION['user'] = new User();
}

$USER = &$_SESSION['user'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a new article, but [this system](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Building-a-CHAP-Login-System-An-ObjectOriented-Approach/) is amazingly good.  There may have been some more recent updates to the original article.